# How to realign numbers from an Integer array to a Jtable?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

Sorry for bad expression to make people confused, i edit my question again.

There is Integer array , it contains 29 numbers, These 29 numbres are made up of 0 to 10.

For example: Integer [ ] num ={ 0,3,4,5,6,1,3,10,4,3,1,0,2,2,3,4,1,0,8,7,6,6,5,8,9,0,5,10,8} I want to realign these numbers into Jtable(limits 6 rows,10 columns).

1. if 0 <= number < 5,i will call them "Small" number;
2. if 5 <= number < 10,i will call them “Big" number;
3. if number = 10, i will call them "P"number.

In a word, the 29 numbers are made up of 3 type number("Samll","Big","P").
In the array num, we can see first three number is belong to "Small" number,so they show one by one in c1,the fourth is 5,it is "Big"number,so it jump to next column, it goes c2,the remaining cells of c1 will not be used again. if the same type number is over 6,it wil turn right to next nearest cell to contiune showing(See 2nd sample image).others array numbers are the same logic,loop the array num and then show the numbers according to the number type in jtable.
The final result what i want in Jtable ,you can see below sample images i post.  Anybody posts sample code will be very helpful to me,Thanks in advance!
[image]

Below sencond sample image, the red underline number total 10 "Small" numbers over 6, so turn to the right nearest cell to contiune showing. The green underline total 7 "Big" numbers ,because the sixth cell in c6 has been occupied， so  it turns right to contiune showing after fifth cell
[image]

Comment: Hint: First split your `num` array up into smaller lists, once you have done that, then you can easily tell how many numbers are in each column, and write some logic to make them turn in the JTable. Note that this is a very messy task, and have a lot of ways to break (what happens when you run out of room because too many columns need to turn? what happens if the last column needs to turn?)...

Comment: @sorifiend   the above is sample one,actually my project has more columns, if too many columns turn, my plan is to delete first column,and add a new column in the last in jtable   for contiuning turn and showing.   if the last column needs to turn ,delete the first column,then add a new in the last again.  But my problem is i cannot figure out how to write the code to make it come ture.

Comment: (1-) Learn to use punctuation and spacing to make your question more readable. A space is added after using a comma (", "), You are also allowed to break the paragraph into multiple paragraphs to make reading easier. I edited some of it, you can do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote code just to create the 6 x 10 `int` matrix.

Here's the output from one of my many tests.

```
  0  5  1 10  4  8  0  5 10  8
  3  6  3     3  7            
  4           1  6            
              0  6            
              2  5  8  9      
              2  3  4  1  0
```

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will help you learn how to create a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

You will want to use a `JTable` to display your matrix.

When tackling a problem like creating your matrix, it helps to break it down into steps.  Keep breaking it down into steps until you can code each step.

This task was so complicated, I had to print debug output to make sure I was making progress.  Don't be afraid to put many `System.out.print` and `System.out.println` statements in your code.  You can use a DEBUG boolean like I did to turn the extra print statements off.

Here's the complete runnable code to create the 6 x 10 matrix.  I didn't check for more than 10 subsets of values.  I left that for you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class RealignNumbers {
    
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RealignNumbers rn = new RealignNumbers();
        int[] numbers = { 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 10, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 
                8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 8, 9, 0, 5, 10, 8 };
        int[][] matrix = rn.realignNumbers(numbers);
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
                if (matrix[row][column] >= 0) {
                    String display = String.format("%3d", matrix[row][column]);
                    System.out.print(display);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public int[][] realignNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        List<List<Integer>> matrixList = splitInput(numbers);
        printList(matrixList);
        
        int[][] matrix = fillMatrix(matrixList);
        return matrix;
    }
    
    private List<List<Integer>> splitInput(int[] numbers) {
        List<List<Integer>> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();
        int number = numbers[0];
        boolean isSmall = number < 5;
        List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
        numberList.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
        
        for (int index = 1; index < numbers.length; index++) {
            if (numbers[index] == 10) {
                // Finish prior List if exists
                if (numberList.size() > 0) {
                    matrixList.add(numberList);
                    numberList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                // Create numberList for 10
                numberList.add(Integer.valueOf(numbers[index]));
                matrixList.add(numberList);
                // Start new List
                numberList = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                boolean small = numbers[index] < 5;
                if (isSmall == small) {
                    // Add number to List
                    numberList.add(Integer.valueOf(numbers[index]));
                } else {
                    // Number is different; end list and start new List
                    matrixList.add(numberList);
                    numberList = new ArrayList<>();
                    numberList.add(Integer.valueOf(numbers[index]));
                    isSmall = small;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (numberList.size() > 0) {
            matrixList.add(numberList);
        }
        
        return matrixList;
    }
    
    private void printList(List<List<Integer>> matrixList) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            int count = 1;
            for (List<Integer> numberList : matrixList) {
                String display = String.format("%2d", count++);
                System.out.print("List " + display + " ");
                for (int number : numberList) {
                    display = String.format("%3d", number);
                    System.out.print(display);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private int[][] fillMatrix(List<List<Integer>> matrixList) {
        int masterColumn = -1;
        int length = 6;
        boolean firstTimeSwitch = true;
        
        int[][] matrix = new int[length][10];
        for (int[] row : matrix) {
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        }
        
        for (List<Integer> numberList : matrixList) {
            masterColumn++;
            int column = masterColumn;
            int row = 0;
            for (int number : numberList) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    System.out.println("row " + row + " column " + column);
                }
                matrix[row][column] = number;
                // Check if we hit the last row
                // If so, increment columns
                if (row < (length - 1)) {
                    row++;
                } else {
                    if (firstTimeSwitch) {
                        length--;
                        firstTimeSwitch = false;
                    }
                    column++;
                }
            }
            
            if (length < 6) {
                firstTimeSwitch = true;
            }
        }
        
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh wow, going above and beyond with this one. It's a very nice answer to cover the logic.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this, then think of a jTable much like a 2D array, for example, `int[][] yourArray = new int[6][10];`.

So the first number in your list goes at `yourArray[0][0] = 0`, and the next two go on the same column `yourArray[1][0] = 3` and `yourArray[2][0] = 4`, and the next number 5 goes into a new column `yourArray[0][1] = 5` and so on.

So when it comes to turning you could do something like this inside the loop that places numbers into the jTable:

```
if(row > rowCount) {
    col++;
    yourTableModel.setValueAt(number, row, col);
}
```

But to make sure that nothing overlaps when turning also use:

```
//Insert value if able
if(yourTableModel.getValueAt(row, col) != null){
    row++;
    yourTableModel.setValueAt(number, row, col);
}
//Move to next col if not able to fit the number within the row
else{
    col++;
    yourTableModel.setValueAt(number, row, col);
}
```